# How to add customized created/modified date to the PDF properties information when using hyperref package?

Tags: hyperref, metadata

Having looked through some posts, I still could not find a solution to this issue.

As `\pdfinfo{...}` is not working while using the package `hyperref`. So I was wondering, how to invoke the commands such as `/CreationDate` `/ModDate` within `\hypersetup`

The following codes will not work while the package `hyperref` is loaded.

```
\pdfinfo{
      /Author {Nicola Talbot}
      /Title  {Creating a PDF document using PDFLaTeX}
      /CreationDate {D:20040502195600}
      /ModDate {...}
      /Keywords {PDF;LaTeX}
       }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the documentation of `hyperref`,

```
\hypersetup{
  pdfinfo={
    Author={Tizio Sempronio},
    Title={Creating a PDF document using PDFLaTeX},
    CreationDate={D:20040502195600},
    ModDate={...},
    Keywords={PDF;LaTeX},
  }
}
```

should work.

Comment: It is not working unfortunately.

Comment: @KOF I forgot to remove a backslash, sorry. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks, i found out the issue is caused by using `pdfauthor = {Name}` or `pdftitle{Title}` outside `pdfinfo`

Comment: I get diff md5 for each build using this approach, so not working?

Comment: @KcFnMi By default, the PDF file contains a time stamp that changes at each build.