# Checking if layout (.pdf or .dvi) has changed after deleting LaTeX comments and/or unused macros from the source .tex file

Tags: comments

**Edit.** My question can be reworded as: *"How can I check, by **command line**, if different sources generate **exacty**  the same `.pdf` layout?"*

I'm improving some `emacs` scripts of mine that I wrote to remove comments and/or unused macros from the source .tex file.

Here's a sample or my code:

```
(save-buffer)
(call-process-shell-command
 (concat "latex \"\\let\\oldExecuteOptions\\ExecuteOptions\"\\\n"
     "\"\\def\\ExecuteOptions#1{\\oldExecuteOptions{#1,draft}}\"\\\n"
     "\"\\nonstopmode\\input{" (buffer-name) "}\";"
     "mv " (file-name-sans-extension (buffer-name)) ".pdf /tmp/"  ) nil nil)

;;; =========================================================================
;;; =========================== "COMMENT" AMBIENT ===========================
;;; =========================================================================

;;The "comment" ambient is defined in the "verbatim" e "comment packages"
(if (string-match-p "\\\\includecomment[\s\t\n]*{comment}" (buffer-string))
    (read-string "SOME WARNING HERE...")

  ;; *ELSE*
  (progn
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (search-forward-regexp "\\\\begin[\s\t\n]*{comment}" nil t)
      (save-excursion
    (let ((b (make-marker))
          (e (make-marker)))
      (set-marker b (match-beginning 0))
      (search-forward-regexp "\\\\end[\s\t\n]*{comment}" nil t)
      (set-marker e (point))
      (goto-char b)
      (unless (nth 4 (syntax-ppss))

        (comment-region b e))
      )))
    (save-buffer)
    (call-process-shell-command
     (concat "latex \"\\let\\oldExecuteOptions\\ExecuteOptions\"\\\n"
         "\"\\def\\ExecuteOptions#1{\\oldExecuteOptions{#1,draft}}\"\\\n"
         "\"\\nonstopmode\\input{" (buffer-name) "}\"" ) nil nil)
    )
  )
```

As can be seen:

1. I first compile my source by passing the `draft` option by command line, saving/moving my output in the `/tmp/` directory.
2. Then I "comment" (with `%`) and remove the "comment" ambients from the source `.tex` file.
3. Finally I compile my `cleaned` source, again with the `draft` option...

So I first have:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\pdfoutput=1
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{comment}

\blindtext

\end{comment}

\end{document}
```

and then

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\pdfoutput=1
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

My question is: "How can I check by **command line**, if the layout has (or not) changed?".

I tried to compare the two pdfs by command line:

```
cmp mydoc.pdf /tmp/mydoc.pdf
```

but it always says that the files are different. But I know the layout has unchanged.

If I try with `diffpdf` (a GUI program) it says "the pdfs appear to be the same" but, as I said, I need a command line solution. I mean I need to get the comparison result in the `stdout` of my terminal so I can use it in my scripts (e.g. with the `emacs`' `shell-command-to-string` fuction). I do not need (and I don't want) to visual check the layout in this stage.

Please, let me know if I've been able to explain my purpose in a clear way.

**NOTE.** This is a dummy example but in some cases could be tricky to check if some changes will affect the layout.

> **My considerations.** After many attempts using a "file content" approach (I tried a `faketime` command approach (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229605/33634)) but it works only with small and simple files) I'm convinced that I need a "layout approach". A tool like `diffpdf` (with the `--appearance` option) that could echo in the `stdout` could be the solution.

Comment: I don't think you mean `layout` itself. The content of the document has changed and you can check this difference by something simple like a `md5sum` hash  or similar  programs or `\pdfmdfivesum` from within `pdflatex` itself. If there's a single white space character more or less than before the md5 hash sums will differ

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It's weird... The md5sum technique works with latex/dvi compilation but doesn't with pdflatex or latex/pdfoutput=1 compilation.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I made some tests and I found that the md5sum hash of a .`dvi` file is related to the system clock. If I compile a file at 9:03 and then I compile again the same file at 9:04... I will get two different hashcodes. I suppose that the same happens with the pdflatex compiler but with a littler time interval.

Comment: pdftex inserts a creation date in the pdf, this will normally change at every compilation. See `SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH` and related subjects in the pdftex documentation.

Comment: In many pdf viewer it is fairly easy to copy the content of the entire pdf file as a text. Then you can compare the content of these texts.

Comment: @Name Comparing texts isn't enough for my purpose. I need to check if the two pdfs are identical in any single detail.

Comment: If you copy the text of a page in sumatrapdf reader for example, not only the text is copied, but also the structure and formulas are also converted to some text. In my opinion it is worth to have a try.

Comment: @Name Since I need to perform this operation in my "copy editor" workflow, this is a very sensitive issue. Also I need a fast command line solution that avoids me, in the most cases, to visual inspect the layout.