# How to specify email and website in a standard way in LaTeX PDF

Tags: pdf, metadata

I am using XeLaTeX and have [found on this site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94484/how-to-add-customized-created-modified-date-to-the-pdf-properties-information-wh) to use the following (that works on XeLaTeX) for generating the very basic PDF metadata (title, subject, author, keywords, date):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
  pdfinfo={
    Author={The Author},
    Creator={The Author},
    Title={The Title},
    Subject={The Subject},
    CreationDate={D:20040502195600},
    ModDate={D:20040502195600},
    Keywords={foo,bar},
    Producer={xelatex}
  }
}

\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

I read somewhere on the PDF specification which I can't seem to find right now, about the ability to specify custom metadata as long as it fits some standard/convention or something. So I'm wondering if there is a standard way to add the email and website to the metadata of the PDF (and any other potentially useful metadata one might like to add). In XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just supply additional key-value pairs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
  pdfinfo = {
    Author       = {The Author},
    Creator      = {The Author},
    Title        = {The Title},
    Subject      = {The Subject},
    CreationDate = {D:20040502195600},
    ModDate      = {D:20040502195600},
    Keywords     = {foo,bar},
    Producer     = {xelatex},
    Something    = {Something else},
    Another      = {Another key with a value}
  }
}

\begin{document}

Hello

\end{document}
```

However, visibility of these key-value pairs might be viewer-dependent; the above visual is within Adobe Reader under the Custom tab within the Document Properties (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>). As mentioned in the dialog window:

> You can add custom properties to this document. Each custom property requires 
>   a unique name, which must not be one of the standard property names Title,
>   Author, Subject, Keywords, Creator, Producer, CreationDate, ModDate, and
>   Tagged.

This is independent of the engine used.